# how to get specific field in serialiser with related_name by Django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have model named ContactPhone and in the model link to Lead model with field lead_id and ralated_name phones

```
class ContactPhone(models.Model):
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, default='')
    phone_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        choices=ContactPhoneInterface.phone_number_types,
        default=PhoneNumbers.mobile.name
    )
    contact_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Contact,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name='phones_c'
    )
    lead_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Lead,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name='phones'
    )
```

by this serilizer class i got id of ContactPhone table, but i need got phone_number field in ContactPhone.

```
class LeadListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            'id',
            'full_name',
            'responsible_id',
            'phones',
            'emails',
        )
```

tried different options to solve this problem but it doesn't help. In the screenshot you can see response of this moment, id of ContactPhone

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a list of specific fields from a related model you can use a [serializers.SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield)

```
class LeadListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    phones = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='phone_number'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            'id',
            'full_name',
            'responsible_id',
            'phones',
            'emails',
        )
```

EDIT: The ContactPhone.phone_number field is not serializable

One option is to set the `__str__` method of the ContactPhone model to return the phone number and use a StringRelatedField

```
class ContactPhone(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.phone_number)


class LeadListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    phones = serializers.StringRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            'id',
            'full_name',
            'responsible_id',
            'phones',
            'emails',
        )
```

Or adding a property that returns the string of phone_number to the ContactPhone model and using that in a SlugRelatedField is potential option

```
class ContactPhone(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def phone_number_str(self):
        return str(self.phone_number)


class LeadListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    phones = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='phone_number_str'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            'id',
            'full_name',
            'responsible_id',
            'phones',
            'emails',
        )
```

Comment: i got error `Object of type PhoneNumber is not JSON serializable`  @iain-shelvington

Comment: The phone_number field is some strange type, what is a `PhoneNumberField` and where does it come from?

Comment: that is an third party app and used for store phone number [link]https://pypi.org/project/django-phonenumber-field/